# Excel - Data Validation Format

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I need to set data validation on an excel cell to be a specific format. I haven't been able to figure it out myself so far.

The requirements are:

- 20 characters in length
- first 4 characters have to be numeric
- characters 5&6 have to be '00'
- characters 7-18 need to be alphanumeric
- characters 19&20 need to be numeric

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This would need to be done with VBA as Excel's default validation is not broad enough for this. This seems like something that should be done in separate columnds though, one for each character set, so the concatenated field at the end would only have validation for 20 characters and the rest could have validation of their own - try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom formula like:

```
=and(Len(A1)=20,isnumber(left(A1,4)+0),mid(A1,5,2)="00",isnumber(right(A1,2)+0))
```

and make sure to uncheck the Ignore blank option.

Note: this would actually allow any characters for 7-18. If it has to be restricted to A-Z and 0-9 that will require an addition to the formula.

Edit:

Based on the clarified requirements, I would suggest VBA be involved. Add a new module with this function:

```
Function IsValid(InputText As String) As Boolean
    IsValid = UCase$(InputText) Like "####00[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]##"
End Function
```

Then select the first cell to which you want to apply the data validation - I'll assume A1. Using Name Manager, define a name called IsValidEntry using the formula:

```
=IsValid(A1)
```

If your DV cell is not A1, use the appropriate address here but do not include any $ signs.

Now in the DV settings you can choose Custom, uncheck the Ignore Blanks option, and use =IsValidEntry as the source.

Comment: It does have to be restricted down to A-Z and 0-9. Is there a difference between restricting it to A-Z & a-z?

Comment: Yes. Does it have to be upper case?

Comment: OK, I've added a different method to my answer as the formula would be horrific for this without VBA!

Comment: Will look into it! Thanks :)